# Grab a wordlist to a python code on linux

Tags: python

Check out this code, what should I do if I want this code to grab words randomly from a wordlist until it get something called flag?

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
import os

BLOCK_SIZE = 32

PADDING = '{'

# Encrypted text to decrypt
encrypted = "Z5p+ZK9f8m9z+wVHw2SsvS0qT0DtqiTY1+yStCzXvP4="

DecodeAES = lambda c, e:   c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)

secrets = #here you need to open words.txt

for secret in secrets:
if (secret[-1:] == "\n"):
    print("Error, new line character at the end of the string. This will not match!")
elif (len(secret) >= 32):
    print ("Error, string too long. Must be less than 32 characters.")

else:
    # create a cipher object using the secret
    cipher = AES.new(secret + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(secret) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING)

    # decode the encoded string
    decoded = DecodeAES(cipher, encrypted)

    if (decoded.startswith('FLAG:')):
        print ("\n")
        print ("Success: "+secret+"\n")
        print (decoded+"\n")
    else:
        print ('Wrong password')
```

I tried to import it using modules and still having the same problem

Comment: it's connected to a wordlist called words.txt ...

Answer (score 0):

When you say `if (secret[-1:] == "\n"):` you are getting all possibilities, because every line in a text file will end with a newline character.  You can take that out and define `secrets` as `[line.strip() for line in open("secrets.txt")]`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you know how to open and read a file; that's trivial to find in many on-line materials.

Note that your code goes through the word list sequentially.  To grab entries randomly, try this:

```
import random

word_list = [
    "apple",
    "baker",
    "cat",
    "FLAG:",
    "gorilla"
]

word = random.choice(word_list)
while not word.startswith("FLAG:"):
    print word
    word = random.choice(word_list)
```

Output of one longer run:

```
cat
apple
apple
gorilla
cat
cat
baker
cat
FLAG: stop here 
   DONE
```